# Get Search Count in WordPress WooCommerce Category Search

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, categories

After my search query (with redirect to the main WP shop page ) my URL looks like

```
.../online-shop/?s=test&product_cat=0&post_type=product
```

I echo the count of the search results in the main WP shop template with the following code - which works fine

```
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?>
```

BUT unfortunately, the code doesn't work if a category is set to the search

```
.../online-shop/?s=test&product_cat=beauty&post_type=product
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: All my test products  starting with the title "test..." - and there are enough posts in the beauty category...  The search works fine without a category selected - but it does not display a count number. i also dont use a search.php file...

Comment: Ok - found a solution - what you think about `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts;`

Comment: I dont know why, but `global $wp_query; with $wp_query->found_posts;` doesnt work in my case...

Comment: if `echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts;` works just use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research i found a solution. The following works in both scenarios:

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->found_posts; ?>
```

Hope it helps others too…

Comment: @LoictheAztec - i stuck again with another problem, maybe you have some idea? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139704/get-category-name-from-wordpress-search-results-page[link]

Comment: I have no ideas right now that could help you… Sorry :(

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - i hope you did see the edit with `echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );` - but i have no clue how to change it so it echos the current category name... thx