# Get Category Name from WordPress Search Results Page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search

After a search query in a specific Blog Category (with redirect to the main WP BLOG page) my search URL looks like

```
.../online-shop/?s=&category=new-posts-category&post_type=post
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to echo the category Name (new-posts-category) in the search Results page. I guess I tried all possible ways I found on the WordPress Codex (like [Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_term_title/) - which works fine by the way in my woocommerce search results) page so far. Any idea how to solve this issue?

**EDIT:**

The closest I came so far is ([Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/))

```
$categories = get_the_category(); 
    // if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
// }
```

But this one echoes the name of the first array element ([0]) of $categories. And I have no idea how to change this so it echoes the current category name - it is by the way the only version which outputs any result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this within the post loop:

```html
$postcat = get_the_category_list( '|','',$post->ID );

echo $postcat;
```

Comment: Im on the search result page form a specific category  - look at the example url in the question please. Your code echos the category of the first post of the search result... So this doesnt work. thx

Comment: So you just want to show the current category title?

Comment: Try       $categories = get_queried_object();
            $category_name = $categories->name;

Comment: tried - i used your suggestion and  `echo  $category_name` - the result is a notice `Trying to get property of non-object in`

Comment: Sorry to keep throwing suggestions your way but its hard to nail your requirements without being able to test my solution, I think your solution was close but you need to add in the post id to get the current categories: $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);